# When i download csv file containing language other than english (ex: Chinese or Japanese language) it turn into symbol on my excel

Tags: excel, csv

When i download csv file containing language other than english (ex: Chinese or Japanese language) it turn into symbol on my excel. I'm learning data analysis and downloaded it from kaggle[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts4Tg.jpg)

i tried search the problems on yt and google and haven't found the solution. anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You probably selected the incorrect code-page when you imported the csv into excel. By the way, the screenshot of the csv you posted is useless for troubleshooting your problem. Excel's Data from Picture option is not reliable.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.